# Having some problems with these method "manifestmerger.enabled=true"

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-support-library, android-launcher, installation-package

I want to use all the Activities of a library for these i had kept manifestmerger.enabled=true in project.properties file of main application and had runned it, it worked but on off single installations of my application on the device it shows two launcher icons(launcher activities) where i can launch my application from both launcher.,.,. i think first one is  for main application and the second one is for Library application as i  used manifestmerger.enabled=true.So, now any one please help me to solve these problem to not get two launcher activities in my application.
Thanks,